# Next.js - static rendering icons not static

Tags: next.js

Thanks for your time.

I am working on a complicated next project for work. I understand it to be a static site generator and the assets (icons for buttons) used on the page are gathered via a pre build script and stored in the public directory of this project. This next project then generates forms, which i am observing unexpected behaviour on.

When looking at the network tab and loading one of the forms the page requests the icons and loads / renders my page, at completion of the load a GraphQl request is made for background data.

This should now be the finished state, there is no change to the page and there is no need for re-render / the components these icons sit within are not updated and a re-render does not happen, however...

A new network request is made and the assets/icons in my components flicker/reload, by what i think is by the framework - why is this new request made? Is this something that the framework is doing? Initiator looks like this - so i think so, but can't see any reason / documentation for it.

`_next/static/chunks/framework-2191d16384373197bc0a.js`

Comment: It could be the `priority` property, by default it's `false`. Try setting that property to `true`... Take a look at [caching behavior](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#caching-behavior) it may be helpful as well.

Comment: What's the verdict, have you tried the suggestion yet?

Comment: Yes , thank you - disableStaticImages is/was set as true in next config (this has to be related), i tried disabling and that was not the cause  adding adding minimumCacheTTL does not fix. 

It is not happening in in the local build (although the gql request fails - stubbed success and same result) so i think it has to be related to the build and the form loader. Feel like the disableStaticImages needs to be false (was probably true for performance), and minimumCacheTTL set to hold image to prevent additional requests - but that does not solve, so looking into that/formloader today.

Comment: Finally have a answer. Bad architecture. 

This was not simply limited to the images. We had/have a stateContext which we have been dispatching to, that context is what is causing the re-render, its not state so each update re-renders everything at a global level. The re-render was not paid any attention to until we throttled and noticed the flickering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally have a answer. Bad architecture in the application.

This was not simply limited to the images. We had a stateContext which we have been dispatching to for everything, that context is what is causing the re-render, its not state so each update re-renders everything at a global level so each button press / graphql query response caused a re-render.

The re-render was not paid any attention to until we throttled and noticed the flickering of these icons.